# How is $ \phi_1\partial_\mu\phi_2-\phi_2\partial_\mu\phi_1 $ a primary field?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I am trying to understand why $$
\phi_1\partial_\mu\phi_2-\phi_2\partial_\mu\phi_1
$$
is a primary field that we can consider in a CFT, provided that $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are primary. Since I see derivatives there I would assume that this term would be a descendant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A descendant is not something that has derivatives in it. It is something that is a total derivative of something else $\mathcal{O}' = \partial_\mu \mathcal{O}$. More precisely, the definition of a primary operator is
$$
K_\mu \mathcal{O}(x) = 0\,,
$$
where $K_\mu$ is the generator of [special conformal transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_conformal_transformation).

You can prove that you operator is a descendant by using the conformal algebra and the fact that the $\phi_i$'s are primaries themselves
$$
K_\mu\, \phi_i(0) = 0\,,\qquad [K_\mu,P_\nu] = 2i\,(\delta_{\mu\nu} D - M_{\mu\nu})\,.
$$
$D$ generates dilatations and $M_{\mu\nu}$ generate spin
$$
D \,\phi_i(0) = \Delta_i \phi_i(0)\quad(\mbox{no sum})\,,\qquad M_{\mu\nu}\phi_i(0) = 0\,.
$$
It suffices to do some algebra and see
$$
K_\nu (\phi_1\partial_\mu \phi_2 - \phi_2 \partial_\mu \phi_1) = 2i\delta_{\mu\nu}\,(\Delta_2 - \Delta_1)\,\phi_1\phi_2\,.
$$

So this operator is actually a primary only if the two operators have the same scaling dimension.

Comment: Thanks @MannyC ! Could you elaborate as to why a primary operator has to obey $K_\mu\mathcal{O}(x)=0$? Is that just a definition?

Comment: Also could you show the calculation explicitly ?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the definition. The only step I skipped is to use
$K_\mu \partial_\nu = \partial_\nu K_\mu + 2 i \delta_{\mu\nu} D$. I had a typo in the last equation that now is fixed. I also did not mention it but one can identify $\partial_\mu = P_\mu$, modulo a factor of $i$ that does not matter here.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't seem to figure out how the $K_\nu$'s disappear  from the calculation.

Comment: After you commute it with $\partial_\mu$ it acts on the other $\phi$ and gives zero again.